# Maximum transaction fees possible & maximum ada needed for collateral as per current protocol parameters

Tags: fee

As per my understanding, the formula to calculate for the transaction fees is `a * tx' + b` where `tx'` is the size of the transaction (in bytes).

Now the current value of `a` & `b` is `44` & `155381` respectively and bounding `tx'` by `16384`, I get that fees is always `<= 0.876277` ada. And therefore the ada only balance needed as collateral should always be `<= ⌈1.5 * 0.876277⌉ = 1.314416` ada (collateral percentage is set to 150 inside current protocol parameters).

Is the above formulation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is correct if no Plutus script is executed in the transaction. If a Plutus script validates the transaction, then one needs to add the cost of the most costly possible Plutus script. Here is a recipe: [Language.Marlowe.Runtime.Transaction.Constraints.maximumFee](https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-cardano/blob/b1ef6295e1a566d70fdf3ac07796b858686b5aca/marlowe-runtime/tx/Language/Marlowe/Runtime/Transaction/Constraints.hs#L417-L428).

The `collateralPercentage` procotol parameter will tell you how much greater than the fee the collateral requirement is. [Currently it is 150%.](https://cexplorer.io/params).